# How to list installed grunt-plugins

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-plugins

I have installed many grunt plugins so that I do not know do a plugin had been installed when I want use it.
how to list installed grunt plugins.

Comment: How about just looking in `package.json`?

Comment: That way could just know what plugins already used in this package.

Comment: Then I don't know what plugins you're referring to... Where exactly are they installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grunt --help lists entry per installed plugin. Mentioned package.json is a place to see whether a project contains certain plugin.

**Edit:**

As you pointed, these are the plugins of certain project only. You wanted to know what plugins you installed to your machine.

If you installed them via npm, please use

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

**Source:** http://ponderingdeveloper.com/2013/09/03/listing-globally-installed-npm-packages-and-version/

Comment: You may remove -g and you get also non-global installs. Actually I got most comprehensive list without -g.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is old, but if anyone is new to Grunt and looking for the same information then this will help.

You can check all the installed plugins in the `package.json` file, that is if you have used the `--save-dev` flag. 
You should see something like this.

```
....
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.4.0"
    }
....
```

If you have not used the flag, you can see the installed plugin in the `node_modules` folder.

```
 /- node_modules/
    +- grunt
    +- grunt-contrib-concat
    +- grunt-contrib-copy
    +- grunt-contrib-cssmin
    +- grunt-contrib-watch
    +- time-grunt
```

You can also see all the installed plugin in your cmd by executing `npm list --depth=0`. The `-g` is for global, if you use `npm list -g --depth=0` It will list out the installed plugin globally, but if you want to check the plugin installed locally then use without `-g`.

If you want to know more about grunt plugin installation/uninstall and some detailed information of the plugins -- you can visit here >> http://www.beekeeperstudio.com/category/grunt/.